# Select and apply function to particular group after groupby

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe:

```
user   group   period
1      1       1
2      2       1
3      2       1
1      1       2
2      1       2
3      1       2
4      2       2
```

I want to make a new column ("period1") in the dataframe that would show the group number to which a user was assigned in period = 1. So it should look like this:

```
user   group   period  period1
    1      1       1   1
    2      2       1   2
    3      2       1   2
    1      1       2   1
    2      1       2   2
    3      1       2   2
    4      2       2   null
```

I tried to use groupby with the condition inside but it didn't help me:

```
df['period1']=df['group'].groupby([df['user'],df['period']==1]).transform(lambda s: max(s))
```

Please help!

Comment: Are you sure that the expected output you posted is correct?

Comment: edited it, is correct now

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) by filtere rows if period is `1`:

```
df['period1'] = df['user'].map(df[df['period']==1].set_index('user')['group'])
print (df)
   user  group  period  period1
0     1      1       1      1.0
1     2      2       1      2.0
2     3      2       1      2.0
3     1      1       2      1.0
4     2      1       2      2.0
5     3      1       2      2.0
6     4      2       2      NaN
```

If need integers:

```
df['period1']=df['user'].map(df[df['period']==1].set_index('user')['group']).astype('Int64')
print (df)
   user  group  period  period1
0     1      1       1        1
1     2      2       1        2
2     3      2       1        2
3     1      1       2        1
4     2      1       2        2
5     3      1       2        2
6     4      2       2     <NA>
```

Answer (score 1):

First you need to filter the dataframe for period 1:

```
period1 = df[df['period'] == 1]
```

Then merge between the two:

```
df = df.merge(right=period1[['user','period']], on='user', how = 'left')
```